# Trigger an event in Angular if users opened a link from an email, or typed in manual url

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I need to trigger an event, when a user gets to the application from clicking a link or typing in the URL to the page manually, however the events do not trigger in either of these scenarios, so cannot rely on checking for URL changes.

For the link clicking, I can force the users to a specific route and do what I need to do, via that, unfortunately, if they copy and paste an existing link, or have book-marked the link previously, I cannot action my custom event.

Is there a known why of handling a scenario like this through the router engine?

Comment: I think you can just use query prameter for this

Comment: what about putting the event logic in a guard, add the guard to the route and the guard will run every time that route is accessed